# IMPORTXML Syntax on google docs

Tags: xml, xpath

I have tried multiple different formats for the syntax I am trying to pull a specific value from this XML API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eveapi version="2">
    <currentTime>2017-01-02 11:59:29</currentTime>
    <result>
        <state>4</state>
        <stateTimestamp>2017-01-02 12:13:29</stateTimestamp>
        <onlineTimestamp>2016-12-16 03:13:10</onlineTimestamp>
        <generalSettings>
            <usageFlags>3</usageFlags>
            <deployFlags>0</deployFlags>
            <allowCorporationMembers>1</allowCorporationMembers>
            <allowAllianceMembers>1</allowAllianceMembers>
        </generalSettings>
        <combatSettings>
            <useStandingsFrom ownerID="99005805"/>
            <onStandingDrop standing="0"/>
            <onStatusDrop enabled="0" standing="0"/>
            <onAggression enabled="0"/>
            <onCorporationWar enabled="1"/>
        </combatSettings>
        <rowset name="fuel" key="typeID" columns="typeID,quantity">
            <row typeID="16275" quantity="9300"/>
            <row typeID="4051" quantity="12110"/>
        </rowset>
    </result>
    <cachedUntil>2017-01-02 12:37:11</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

The value I'm looking for is the Quanity on this line:

```
<row typeID="4051" quantity="12140"/>
```

Thank you, I've tried multiple ways and I cant seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath will find `row` element where `typeID` attribute equals 4051, and then return corresponding `quantity` attribute value :

```
=importxml("URL here...", "//row[@typeID='4051']/@quantity")
```

Comment: So with that I'm getting a "imported content is empty" I want it to return the value in quantity on that line. Any idea why its not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the value of this line (which is *empty*)

```
<row typeID="4051" quantity="12110"/>   <!-- I fixed the value from 12140 to 12110 -->
```

you could use this XPath expression:

```
//row[@typeID='4051' and @quantity='12110']/text()
```

If you just want to get the attribute value of the `quantity` attribute of the `row/@typeID` node, you could use this simpler expression

```
//row[@typeID='4051']/@quantity
```

which would return '12110' with your given XML.

Comment: So the return i'm getting with 


    `//row[@typeID='4051']/@quantity`


Is "Imported content is empty" so its not returning the value to my sheet.

I've tried using both of those expressions and get the same thing. That is the value I want displayed.